# How to cache this in C#?

Tags: c#

I'am new in C#.
I Really wanted to cache this since i need to call it on Update method.
Its create a lot of garbage collection.

```
 private bool IsPointerOverUIObject() {
     PointerEventData eventDataCurrentPosition = new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current);
     eventDataCurrentPosition.position = new Vector2(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y);
     List<RaycastResult> results = new List<RaycastResult>();
     EventSystem.current.RaycastAll(eventDataCurrentPosition, results);
     return results.Count > 0;
 }
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to cache this result? What if the mouse pointer moves?

Comment: Is there anyway to minimize garbage collection from calling this on update method? i wanted to make mobile game and make UI ignore click

Comment: Why not move `IsPointerOverUIObject()` into the click/touch event handler then? No need to check if no one clicks

Comment: You're right. Thanks. Lemme tried it

Comment: What profiling or research have you done to reach the conclusion that this causes a significant GC overhead? A very common problem, especially for new programmers, is to worry about the wrong things. Because of this the general recommendation is to profile first.  In this specific case you are creating a few short lived objects a couple of times a second, this is usually handled very well by the GC.

Answer (score 0):

Caching the result is probably not the right solution here - caching information dependent on mouse/touch pointer location means your game might produce unexpected/delayred results when the user moves their finger.

From your comments:

> [I] wanted to make mobile game and make UI ignore click

In that case, you can probably reduce computation overhead most effectively by moving the `IsPointerOverUIObject()` call into the event trigger for the relevant click/touch event - there's no need to check where a click or touch release occurs unless someone is actually touching the screen.